# Detect processor during preseed post-install script

Tags: preseed

Is it possible to detect the processor, such as by `uname -p`, from within a preseed post-install script? `uname -p` returns `unknown`, and `in-target uname -p` returns nothing.

I ask because I need to fetch and install an architecture-specific .deb file from within the script.

Comment: you mean like `sudo cat /proc/cpu`

Comment: Sort of (assuming you mean `/proc/cpuinfo`), but even accessing /proc from preseed sounds [complicated](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21145/how-can-i-check-processor-flags-inside-a-preseed-install). Then you have to parse out the architecture yourself by grepping for various keywords that identify x86-32, x86-64, ARM, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `uname` is implemented by BusyBox during preseed, and it supports `uname -m` but not `uname -p`. You can verify in a normal shell with BusyBox installed:

```
$ uname -p
x86_64
$ busybox uname -p
unknown
$ busybox uname -m
x86_64
```

In all the cases I care about, the values happen to be the same.